# Flyway - libjvm.dylib issue in MacOs

Tags: macos, flyway

While I was setting up flyway on my Mac, when I tried to execute the command `./flyway info` to verify all the configuration I've done properly, I used to get error saying -

```
libjvm.dylib” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
```

Answer (score 5):

To resolve the above issue, I followed below mentioned steps:-

1. Go to JRE LIB folder of flyway installation folder - for me this path looks
   something like this - `flyway-8.5.4/jre/lib`
2. Type this command
   `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 xattr -d com.apple.quarantine`
3. Click cancel on the original `libjvm.dylib`  dialog and execute the flyway command
   again. It should resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a recent version of JAVA installed - you can use it instead of the one bundled with the flyway tar.
For some reason, flyway prefers the bundled JRE over $JAVA_HOME, but if you rename the bundled `jre` folder to something else, say `jre_old`,  and JAVA_HOME is set - it will run flyway with your local JAVA and this error would be gone.